# I want to bake vps which is nignix on

Tags: linux, nginx, nginx-config

I have a vps on which the files are, nignix must be there, I want to enter via ip that is shared, i.e. 51.38.137.201, to transfer us to another link, I made a script that worked for me but I do not know where to insert it in nignix
if ($http_useragent !~* "") {
return [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8UT0OBaaJ4;}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8UT0OBaaJ4;%7D)

I just know that this script should be in the deafult file in sites-available

Answer (score 0):

Insert this in your default configuration located in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default and make your changes to it.

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name olddomain.com;
   return 301 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8UT0OBaaJ4$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: unknown directive "%7D$request_uri" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:96
did not work

Comment: my bad, try 

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name olddomain.com;
   return 301 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8UT0OBaaJ4$request_uri;
}

Comment: I don't understand you have any discord to explain because I don't get it

Comment: You just have to copy paste into your configuration and it redirects you to your Youtube Video :D
just do it like this in the terminal:

cp /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default /home; rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default;
touch /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default; nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

copy paste my answer in the code block
Save the file with CTRL + X and hit y

type:
sudo service nginx reload

and it works